# Storage Issues & slow booting with MBP 2014

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, battery, storage

I own a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014), here are the details

[image]

Recently I've been facing two issues.

#### 1. Slow Booting

It takes around 20+ minutes just to boot. I've looked at my login items and disabled everything, it still doesn't help.

#### 2. Storage fills up to max for no reason

As I'm using the laptop, the storage keeps filling up under "Other". After a fresh boot, I have 90GB of free space, but as I keep using my laptop it increases and eventually goes upto storage full. Here's an example, only 32GB is available from my actual 90GB free space after a while of use. The only option to revert this is to reboot, again that takes a long time especially if it's after the max storage problem.

[image: Here's an example]

---

Also macOS recommends a battery service, it says my battery capacity if significantly reduced, I don't think anyone provides this service in my country, but I should be good as long as I always have a charger right?

Can anyone help me with diagnosing this issue and fixing it? I'm very hesitant to reinstall macOS because I'm working on something important and I cannot afford that much of a downtime.

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: macOS Big Sur 11.1 @nohillside

Comment: Booting that slow *could be* a software issue, but it sounds like you eliminated that as a possibility. Have you wiped the drive and reinstalled the OS? Well after that it is possible the drive is failing...

Comment: startup disk: untitled. Usually it should say macintosh HD unless you did *something* out of the ordinary with your mac. Have you done something like a hard drive swap, wipe and reinstall or booting off external devices? Before you do **any** diagnosing create a full backup!

Comment: If you cannot afford the downtime, then you **do** have a backup don't you?

Comment: Did you check in monitoring program if there is a specific process which do disk I/o, cpu usage ?

Comment: Why don't you update the system (actually 11.6). Old versions are often buggy.

Comment: Strongly agree with Jean_JD: Update your OS. If that *still* doesn't fix it, boot in Verbose Mode (CMD+V during boot) and take a slow-motion video of the boot console text. Upload the screencaps from that video here and take note of which points of the process are slow.

Comment: I haven't done that yet, this is the only laptop I have so I fear it might get stuck with a reinstallation @SteveChambers

Comment: I had some issues like a year ago so I gave my laptop for repair to a known friend, I'm just guessing it was renamed. And nope I haven't, got it! @X_841

Comment: Jean_JD I thought it might make the current state worse, I will try updating the OS. Thank you! Pion, will do if the issue still persists after the update, thanks!

Comment: I have a backup for my files, no time machine backup. I will get a hard disk for that I guess. @SolarMike

Comment: Hm, the highest CPU time goes to kernal_task & WindowsServer while the highest CPU% usage goes to storagekitd, WindowsService @PtitXav